# Multiple lines of text into one cell

Tags: excel

I am wondering how to move multiple lines of text from different cells into one cell.

For example

> My
>   dog
>   is
>   brown
>
> My dog is brown

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this command:

`= CONCATENATE ( A1, A2, A3, A4 )`

but it will produce **"My dog si brown"** only if you have the white spaces in the cell "My " "dog "....

If you want to add the white spaces you could do it like so:

`= CONCATENATE ( A1," ", A2," ", A3," ",A4)`

You can find more information [here](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excel2010functions/ss/2011-01-30-excel-2010-concatenate-text-strings.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If cells contain text in this format

```
A1 My
A2 dog
A3 is
A4 brown
```

And the result you need in A5 is

```
A5 My dog is brown
```

Select A5 cell and use this function

```
=CONCATENATE(A1, A2, A3, A4)
```

OR

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ",A2," ",A3," ",A4)
```

to add a space in between texts.

For more information visit office [support](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/combine-the-contents-of-multiple-cells-HA010248390.aspx)